# PMD rule test classes source for benchmarking

Tags: static-analysis, pmd

Are there any test classes where PMD rule can be tested ? Basically i want to benchmark some other tool again PMD's basic rule set. Like PMd must be testing its rule against some test code..

I dugg through PMD source but could not figure out where such classes are.

Answer (score 0):

The [rule guidelines](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rule-guidelines.html) page describes the -benchmark flag where you can see how long a rule takes against given source code - they suggest the JDK code itself.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to test JTest and PMD to see which is better. So i was thinking if there is like tests for "Bad Code" which PMD provides, i can test against it.

Comment: You can run JTest and PMD against the same codebase.  Then you don't need -baseline anymore.  I recently was in a project that migrated from JTest to PMD.  The performance was about the same for the configurations we were using (except for very large code bases).  That said, we had turned off a lot of JTest rules because they were dragging performance and had PMD with many more rules on.